# How to create 8 instances with 500 users each using Non-GUI mode in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement to run 4000 users. I just wanted to run that using Non-GUI. How can we create 8 instances with 500 users each using Non-GUI mode in Jmeter. Suggest the possible scenario with an example.

Answer (score 1):

- Get 9 machines somewhere somehow
- Install [Java 8+](https://openjdk.java.net/install/) (it's the per-requisite to run [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities/))
- Install JMeter onto all machines. If you plan to use [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) make sure that all the plugins are installed on all machines
- If your test depends on external files or libraries - make sure that all the libraries and/or files are copied to the JMeter Machines
- If you plan to use secure communication between master and slaves follow [Setting Up SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) JMeter Documentation chapter, if not - add the next line to *user.properties* files on all machines:

  ```
   server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
  ```
- Run `jmeter-server` on 8 machines which will be acting as slaves
- Add the next line to *user.properties* on the master machine

  ```
   remote_hosts=ip_address_of_slave1,ip_address_of_slave_2, etc.
  ```
- Make sure that the machines are on the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) and there is no [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) blocking connections between them
- Run your test as:

  ```
   jmeter -r -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
  ```
- When the test finishes analyze your results by using [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) or generating [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

More information:

- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: Is there any other way to use this other than Master-slave method?

Comment: Depends on your single machine hardware specifications, given a powerful enough single host, you follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should be able to simulate 4000 users from a single machine